# External Drive Information Not Writing to XML File

Tags: xml, vb.net, console-application

After having success with help from a previous question, I managed to successfully run a VB console app that would pull drive information and write it to an xml file.  When there are no external drives connected, the application runs and processes as expected.  It collects drive information, shows the information in the console app, and writes the appropriate information to a XML file.

Things begin to get weird when I connect External Drives.  The program will either

A.) only write information on the integrated drives within the PC which is the C:\ and D:\ drives or

B.) Not write any information to the XML file at all when enough external drives are connected, even though the console app successfully shows all of the drives that are connected.

Below is my code:

```
Sub Main()
    Dim dt As New DataTable("DriveInformation")

    Dim Column_1st As New DataColumn("Date")
    Dim Column_2nd As New DataColumn("Server")
    Dim Column_3rd As New DataColumn("Drive")
    Dim Column_4th As New DataColumn("TotalSpace")
    Dim Column_5th As New DataColumn("UsedSpace")
    Dim Column_6th As New DataColumn("RemainingSpace")
    Dim Column_7th As New DataColumn("Status")

    dt.Columns.Add(Column_1st)
    dt.Columns.Add(Column_2nd)
    dt.Columns.Add(Column_3rd)
    dt.Columns.Add(Column_4th)
    dt.Columns.Add(Column_5th)
    dt.Columns.Add(Column_6th)
    dt.Columns.Add(Column_7th)

    ' Get information and Write to Console.

    Console.WriteLine("Server Name: {0}", System.Net.Dns.GetHostName)
    Console.WriteLine("Date: {0}", DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd"))
    Console.WriteLine("")

    Dim DriveNumber As Integer = 0
    Dim allDrives() As IO.DriveInfo = IO.DriveInfo.GetDrives()
    Dim d As IO.DriveInfo

    For Each d In allDrives
        DriveNumber = DriveNumber + 1
        Console.WriteLine("Drive {0}", d.Name)
        Console.WriteLine("  Drive type: {0}", d.DriveType)
        If d.IsReady = True And d.TotalSize < 1099511627776 Then
            Console.WriteLine("  Volume label: {0}", d.VolumeLabel)
            Console.WriteLine("  File system: {0}", d.DriveFormat)


            Console.WriteLine(
            "  Total size of drive:   {0, 15} GB ",
            FormatNumber(d.TotalSize / 1024 / 1024 / 1024))


        ElseIf d.IsReady = True And d.TotalSize >= 1099511627776 Then
            Console.WriteLine("  Volume label: {0}", d.VolumeLabel)
            Console.WriteLine("  File system: {0}", d.DriveFormat)



            Console.WriteLine(
            "  Total size of drive:   {0, 15} TB ",
            FormatNumber(d.TotalSize / 1024 / 1024 / 1024 / 1024))
        End If

        If d.IsReady = True And d.TotalSize - d.TotalFreeSpace < 1099511627776 Then



            Console.WriteLine(
                "  Total used space:      {0, 15} GB",
            FormatNumber(d.TotalSize / 1024 / 1024 / 1024 - d.TotalFreeSpace / 1024 / 1024 / 1024))


        ElseIf d.IsReady = True And d.TotalSize - d.TotalFreeSpace >= 1099511627776 Then


            Console.WriteLine(
                "  Total used space:      {0, 15} TB",
                FormatNumber(d.TotalSize / 1024 / 1024 / 1024 / 1024 - d.TotalFreeSpace / 1024 / 1024 / 1024 / 1024))
        End If


        If d.IsReady = True And d.TotalFreeSpace < 1099511627776 Then


            Console.WriteLine(
                "  Total available space: {0, 15} GB",
                FormatNumber(d.TotalFreeSpace / 1024 / 1024 / 1024))
            Console.WriteLine("")

        ElseIf d.IsReady = True And d.TotalFreeSpace >= 1099511627776 Then



            Console.WriteLine(
            "  Total available space: {0, 15} TB",
            FormatNumber(d.TotalFreeSpace / 1024 / 1024 / 1024 / 1024))
            Console.WriteLine("")

        End If

    Next

    ' Put Information into DataTable
    For Each d In allDrives

        DriveNumber = DriveNumber + 1

        If DriveNumber = 1 And d.TotalSize < 1099511627776 Then

            Dim drow1 As DataRow = dt.NewRow

            drow1("Date") = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd")
            drow1("Server") = System.Net.Dns.GetHostName
            drow1("Drive") = d.Name
            drow1("TotalSpace") = FormatNumber(d.TotalSize / 1024 / 1024 / 1024)
            drow1("UsedSpace") = FormatNumber(d.TotalSize / 1024 / 1024 / 1024 - d.TotalFreeSpace / 1024 / 1024 / 1024)
            drow1("RemainingSpace") = FormatNumber(d.TotalFreeSpace / 1024 / 1024 / 1024)
            drow1("Status") = d.IsReady
            dt.Rows.Add(drow1)

        ElseIf DriveNumber = 1 And d.TotalSize >= 1099511627776 Then

            Dim drow1 As DataRow = dt.NewRow

            drow1("Date") = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd")
            drow1("Server") = System.Net.Dns.GetHostName
            drow1("Drive") = d.Name
            drow1("TotalSpace") = FormatNumber(d.TotalSize / 1024 / 1024 / 1024 / 1024)
            drow1("UsedSpace") = FormatNumber(d.TotalSize / 1024 / 1024 / 1024 / 1024 - d.TotalFreeSpace / 1024 / 1024 / 1024 / 1024)
            drow1("RemainingSpace") = FormatNumber(d.TotalFreeSpace / 1024 / 1024 / 1024 / 1024)
            drow1("Status") = d.IsReady
            dt.Rows.Add(drow1)


        End If
        If DriveNumber = 2 And d.TotalSize < 1099511627776 Then

            Dim drow2 As DataRow = dt.NewRow

            drow2("Date") = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd")
            drow2("Server") = System.Net.Dns.GetHostName
            drow2("Drive") = d.Name
            drow2("TotalSpace") = FormatNumber(d.TotalSize / 1024 / 1024 / 1024)
            drow2("UsedSpace") = FormatNumber(d.TotalSize / 1024 / 1024 / 1024 - d.TotalFreeSpace / 1024 / 1024 / 1024)
            drow2("RemainingSpace") = FormatNumber(d.TotalFreeSpace / 1024 / 1024 / 1024)
            drow2("Status") = d.IsReady
            dt.Rows.Add(drow2)

        ElseIf DriveNumber = 2 And d.TotalSize >= 1099511627776 Then

            Dim drow2 As DataRow = dt.NewRow

            drow2("Date") = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd")
            drow2("Server") = System.Net.Dns.GetHostName
            drow2("Drive") = d.Name
            drow2("TotalSpace") = FormatNumber(d.TotalSize / 1024 / 1024 / 1024 / 1024)
            drow2("UsedSpace") = FormatNumber(d.TotalSize / 1024 / 1024 / 1024 / 1024 - d.TotalFreeSpace / 1024 / 1024 / 1024 / 1024)
            drow2("RemainingSpace") = FormatNumber(d.TotalFreeSpace / 1024 / 1024 / 1024 / 1024)
            drow2("Status") = d.IsReady
            dt.Rows.Add(drow2)


        End If
        If DriveNumber = 3 And d.TotalSize < 1099511627776 Then

            Dim drow3 As DataRow = dt.NewRow

            drow3("Date") = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd")
            drow3("Server") = System.Net.Dns.GetHostName
            drow3("Drive") = d.Name
            drow3("TotalSpace") = FormatNumber(d.TotalSize / 1024 / 1024 / 1024)
            drow3("UsedSpace") = FormatNumber(d.TotalSize / 1024 / 1024 / 1024 - d.TotalFreeSpace / 1024 / 1024 / 1024)
            drow3("RemainingSpace") = FormatNumber(d.TotalFreeSpace / 1024 / 1024 / 1024)
            drow3("Status") = d.IsReady
            dt.Rows.Add(drow3)

        ElseIf DriveNumber = 3 And d.TotalSize >= 1099511627776 Then

            Dim drow3 As DataRow = dt.NewRow

            drow3("Date") = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd")
            drow3("Server") = System.Net.Dns.GetHostName
            drow3("Drive") = d.Name
            drow3("TotalSpace") = FormatNumber(d.TotalSize / 1024 / 1024 / 1024 / 1024)
            drow3("UsedSpace") = FormatNumber(d.TotalSize / 1024 / 1024 / 1024 / 1024 - d.TotalFreeSpace / 1024 / 1024 / 1024 / 1024)
            drow3("RemainingSpace") = FormatNumber(d.TotalFreeSpace / 1024 / 1024 / 1024 / 1024)
            drow3("Status") = d.IsReady
            dt.Rows.Add(drow3)


        End If

        If DriveNumber = 4 And d.TotalSize < 1099511627776 Then

            Dim drow4 As DataRow = dt.NewRow

            drow4("Date") = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd")
            drow4("Server") = System.Net.Dns.GetHostName
            drow4("Drive") = d.Name
            drow4("TotalSpace") = FormatNumber(d.TotalSize / 1024 / 1024 / 1024)
            drow4("UsedSpace") = FormatNumber(d.TotalSize / 1024 / 1024 / 1024 - d.TotalFreeSpace / 1024 / 1024 / 1024)
            drow4("RemainingSpace") = FormatNumber(d.TotalFreeSpace / 1024 / 1024 / 1024)
            drow4("Status") = d.IsReady
            dt.Rows.Add(drow4)

        ElseIf DriveNumber = 4 And d.TotalSize >= 1099511627776 Then

            Dim drow4 As DataRow = dt.NewRow

            drow4("Date") = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd")
            drow4("Server") = System.Net.Dns.GetHostName
            drow4("Drive") = d.Name
            drow4("TotalSpace") = FormatNumber(d.TotalSize / 1024 / 1024 / 1024 / 1024)
            drow4("UsedSpace") = FormatNumber(d.TotalSize / 1024 / 1024 / 1024 / 1024 - d.TotalFreeSpace / 1024 / 1024 / 1024 / 1024)
            drow4("RemainingSpace") = FormatNumber(d.TotalFreeSpace / 1024 / 1024 / 1024 / 1024)
            drow4("Status") = d.IsReady
            dt.Rows.Add(drow4)


        End If

        If DriveNumber = 5 And d.TotalSize < 1099511627776 Then

            Dim drow5 As DataRow = dt.NewRow

            drow5("Date") = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd")
            drow5("Server") = System.Net.Dns.GetHostName
            drow5("Drive") = d.Name
            drow5("TotalSpace") = FormatNumber(d.TotalSize / 1024 / 1024 / 1024)
            drow5("UsedSpace") = FormatNumber(d.TotalSize / 1024 / 1024 / 1024 - d.TotalFreeSpace / 1024 / 1024 / 1024)
            drow5("RemainingSpace") = FormatNumber(d.TotalFreeSpace / 1024 / 1024 / 1024)
            drow5("Status") = d.IsReady
            dt.Rows.Add(drow5)

        ElseIf DriveNumber = 5 And d.TotalSize >= 1099511627776 Then

            Dim drow5 As DataRow = dt.NewRow

            drow5("Date") = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd")
            drow5("Server") = System.Net.Dns.GetHostName
            drow5("Drive") = d.Name
            drow5("TotalSpace") = FormatNumber(d.TotalSize / 1024 / 1024 / 1024 / 1024)
            drow5("UsedSpace") = FormatNumber(d.TotalSize / 1024 / 1024 / 1024 / 1024 - d.TotalFreeSpace / 1024 / 1024 / 1024 / 1024)
            drow5("RemainingSpace") = FormatNumber(d.TotalFreeSpace / 1024 / 1024 / 1024 / 1024)
            drow5("Status") = d.IsReady
            dt.Rows.Add(drow5)
        End If



    Next

    ' Write Information to DataTable

    Dim path As String = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop)
    path = IO.Path.Combine(path, "ServerDriveInformation_.xml")
    dt.WriteXml(path)

End Sub
```

While having no external drives connected the Xml will have the output expected.  For comparison the screenshot of the Console App and the XML output will be shown below.

Console App Output:
[image: Console App Output]

XML Output:

[image: XML Output]

However When I connect External Drives this is the result:

Console Application:

[image: Correct Output on Console]

XML Missing E:\ Drive:

[image: XML Missing E:\ Drive]

Things really get odd when I have all Drives connected!

Console Application Output:

[image: All Drives Connected.]

XML Output With All Drives Connected:

[image: XML with all drives connected.]

What could be causing this?  Is there an error in my coding that could be the issue?  Thank you for the time in reviewing the matter.

Comment: You don't reset `DriveNumber` between the two loops.  Also you have a lot of boilerplate around formatting the drive sizes which could be pushed into a separate function and reduce the bulk of your code (so making it easier to follow/debug)

Comment: @Tim Williams thank you!  I removed the DriveNumber - DriveNumber +1 under the For Each d In allDrives line and everything is now functioning correctly!  I am fairly new at coding so I am still learning how to properly place my code into seperate functions to reduce bulk throughout the code.  Thank you very much!